# [Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM700002] Error happened during message fetching Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=403 "(null)"

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I am working on an Angular + Cordova project. I am trying to use the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` plugin for push notifications functionalities. It is doing good for Android and everything seems to work as expected.

However, when I am trying the same for iOS, the build is getting prepared without any issue but on opening the app, the app gets stuck in the splash screen.

I have checked the log from Xcode and below is the error after which the app gets stuck.

```
[Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM700002] Error happened during message fetching Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=403 "(null)"
```

**My Development Environment:**

---

1. Angular - 11
2. Cordova - 11
3. cordova-ios - 6.2.0

---

Any help regarding this is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved when I used the CLI version of the `cordova-plugin-firebasex`. Follow the below link for a detailed explanation:
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#cordova-cli-builds